# Java mail error in webllogic server

Tags: jakarta-mail, weblogic12c

I am trying to send mail(outlook) through weblogic 12c using java mail api
and i am getting this error so please help with this....

com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [BMXPR01CA0016.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2203)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1694)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at roomBooking.sendMail.(sendMail.java:89)
at jsp_servlet.__booking._jspService(__booking.java:163)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:35)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.onAddToMapException(ServletStubImpl.java:489)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:376)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:649)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:224)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3654)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [authenticate to your mail server](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#smtpauth).